# ES6 import hides TypeScript definition file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

I have 2 definition files: foo.d.ts and bar.d.ts

```
// foo.d.ts
interface IBaseInterface {
    // stuff
}

// bar.d.ts 
interface IDerivedInterface extends IBaseInterface {
    // more stuff
}
```

This works fine. The moment I add an ES6 import to foo.d.ts, my entire app is no longer able to "see" the contents of it.

For example, modifying foo.d.ts to the following:

```
// foo.d.ts
import { SomeClass } from 'my-module';

interface IBaseInterface {
    baz: SomeClass;
}
```

Does the following to bar.d.ts:

```
// bar.d.ts
// ERROR: Cannot find name IBaseInterface
interface IDerivedInterface extends IBaseInterface { 

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an `import` to your file makes it a module, which means that things defined in the current file won't be visible to things in the global scope.

To fix this, export `IBaseInterface` and import it from the file you've defined `IDerivedInterface` in. For example, you could write

```
// foo.d.ts
import { SomeClass } from 'my-module';

export interface IBaseInterface {
    baz: SomeClass;
}
```

and

```
// bar.d.ts
import { IBaseInterface } from './foo';

interface IDerivedInterface extends IBaseInterface { 

}
```